# Update columns counting probability using MySQL

Tags: mysql

example table:

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| cat    | dog    |     1 |    0 |
| dog    | cat    |     1 |    0 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

I need to let prob = count/ total of count
and I using

```
update test set prob = count / (select sum(count) from EM);
```

and it failed ,how I suppose to do ?

Comment: This is something you want to store? Why?

Comment: result must be prob row1 = 1/(1+1) row2 = 1/(1+1)

Comment: im assuming in your sample query there, both tables are supposed to be called the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't like referring to the table being updated, in a subquery. To get around it, wrap it in another select to force it to form a temporary table.

```
update test
  set prob = count / (select * from (select sum(count) from test) q )
```